# Trespassing in Portugal

Tags: civil-law, property, trespass, portugal

In Portugal, if people trespass property, what are the legal implications? For example,

1. If a person opens my gate and enters my yard to knock on my door, is he trespassing?
2. If a person enters my office building, passes by security without problem and wanders around the halls, is he trespassing?
3. If a person enters an abandoned factory and passes through a door saying "Restricted Area", is he trespassing?

If any of the examples (or all 3) is considered trespassing, what might happen to the person, according to Portuguese law?

Comment: About Portugese law I know nothing.

Generally, If a person enters your yard to knock on your door, whether he's trespassing depends on the nature of his business. What's happening in this case?

If a person enters your office building, passes by security without problem and wanders around the halls, he is prolly trespassing.

If it's really an "abandoned" factory how could  the designation "Restricted Area" apply, and to whom?